# Data Manipulation in R: Systematically replacing values in a column with strings

Tags: r

I need to replace the values in a column with the corresponding string. In my searches I have come across similar questions with answers that closely match what I am looking for but nothing that fits my needs exactly. Since I am a beginner, it would help if you could explain how this code works.

I want to go from a data set like this

```
    A   B    C    D

1   1   64   20   1
2   2   64   20   3
3   3   64   20   3
4   4   64   20   1
5   5   64   20   2
```

To a dataset that looks like this using the key 1 = Apple, 2 = Blastoise, 3 = Carousel

```
    A   B    C    D

1   1   64   20   Apple
2   2   64   20   Carousel
3   3   64   20   Carousel
4   4   64   20   Apple
5   5   64   20   Blastoise
```

I understand that you can just use something like

```
df$D <- "label"
```

to change the values of the column.

However, I don't know how to get the "label" part to match with the corresponding value.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df$D = factor(df$D, levels = 1:3, labels = c("Apple", "Blastoise", "Carousel"))` would be one good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One baseR option here is to use `merge`.  First, create a dataframe which maps the `D` column values to the labels:

```
labels <- data.frame(D=c(1,2,3), label=c("Apple", "Blastoise", "Carousel"))
```

Then do the merge:

```
result <- merge(df, labels, by="D")

result
  D A  B  C     label
1 1 1 64 20     Apple
2 1 4 64 20     Apple
3 2 5 64 20 Blastoise
4 3 2 64 20  Carousel
5 3 3 64 20  Carousel
```

If you want to preserve the original column order, use:

```
result <- merge(df, labels, by="D")[, union(names(df), names(labels))]
```

Comment: This works pretty well! Thank you! The only downside is that it doesn't really preserve the column order which is relatively minor.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

**Using column D as index:**

`df$D` is a vector containing integers 1, 2 and 3. You must think of them as a collection of indexes. For example:

```
df$D = c(1,3,3,1,2)
```

Another vector contains the names:

```
v_names = c("Apple","Blastoise","Carousel")
```

What happens if you use `df$D` as indexes of `v_names`?

```
v_names[df$D]
[1] "Apple"     "Carousel"  "Carousel"  "Apple"     "Blastoise"
```

You'll get a vector having the same length as the collection of indexes (`df$D`) with the names replacing these index values.

**Using ifelse:**

This way needs as many `ifelse` as names present, so it is not advised.

```
ifelse(df$D==1,"Apple",ifelse(df$D==2,"Blastoise","Carousel"))
[1] "Apple"     "Carousel"  "Carousel"  "Apple"     "Blastoise"
```

As you can see they are nested `ifelse`. Hard to read if there are more than three different cases.

**Using factors**

If you convert your column to factor, then change the levels with the names:

```
df$D = as.factor(df$D)
levels(df$D) = c("Apple","Blastoise","Carousel")

> df$D
[1] Apple     Carousel  Carousel  Apple     Blastoise
Levels: Apple Blastoise Carousel
```

The inconvenience here is that the column is a factor. If you want to do something with the strings you must convert to character first

```
df$D = as.character(df$D)
```